# How to use the ASCII Value of something

Tags: c, file, encryption, ascii

I want to take a character from a file.txt which has only one character , for example "C" and use its ASCII value to turn another file2.txt and change it. For example

C's value = 67

file2.txt has:

```
Hello
World
```

I want it to change each character and turn it to:

Adding H's ASCII value with "C" ASCII value and divide it by two so you get another ASCII Value, which will be the new character on the new file its going to make.

And so the new file is going to be imprinted as "dlroW olleH" with the new ASCII values for each character, like an encryption.

How can I do this without any fancy commands.

My key questions here would be:

1. How can I take the ASCII values and mix em together
2. In case there's a 135.5 when its divided take always the higher number (136) or the lower number(134) because as far as I know there's no  ASCII character with the value of 67.75.
3. How can I make it so the new file is all backwards? The new file should be imprinted as .txt file.

so:

```
file.txt --> Key 
file1.txt -->file to be encrypted
file3.txt encrypted file.
```

Comment: Your proposed algorithm is not reversible - you won't be able to unambiguously (accurately) decrypt the 'encrypted' file.  Use integer division.  All ASCII codes (all character codes) are integer values, so there are no codes like 135.5 or 67.75.

Comment: Why not use a proven algorithm like AES?

Comment: So, what are you guys telling me? The division isn't possible to be run?

Comment: If you do this **with** the division, it's not even encryption, because it's not reversible, you're throwing away the LSB of each char. If you do it **without** the division, it will work, but in practice it will make a really awful encryption scheme, because it can be broken simply by tabulating letter frequencies (as long as the language is guessed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1.) How can I take the ASCII values and mix em together*

That's called a [transposition cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher), however:

dividing (chr1 + chr2)/2 is an unworkable suggestion (irreversible, as Jonathan L says) because you'll throw away the lowest bit from chr2.
No matter how you do rounding, consider that your encryption will map the 26 values {'A','B','C',...'Z'} to only 13 (or 14). It's not a bijection, you lose information.

So just don't do the division.

```
char transpose = whatever;
int transpose_offset = transpose-'A';
char encrypt(char in, int transpose_offset) {
   return ((in-'A') + transpose_offset) % 26 + 'A';
}
```

(Dividing by 2 is equivalent to a right-shit >> 1. Instead of that you could preserve the information by doing a circular-shift. But anyway, that doesn't buy you much, it's trivial to break a transposition cipher by tabulating it.)

*3.) How can I make it so the new file is all backwards?*

Easy. Either do the encryption working backwards through the sourcetext, and write it out as you go. Or else encrypt going forwards, store the result and write out backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing by two, you can xor the bytes of the file to be encrypted with the bytes of the key produce an encrypted file. Then you can run it again for decryption.